# Gnome Tweaks Appearance section layout is messed up

Tags: gnome, gnome-tweaks

I have no clue how but the Appearance section layout is messed up!
The dropdown boxes' width is stretched and it's causing the Gnome Tweaks left panel to disappear if I decrease the width of the window.
I've included pictures of dropdown boxes and Gnome Tweaks window after i decreased width.
What's happening and how can i fix it?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

I've already tried changing the theme, the problem still remains.

[image: dropdown boxes]
[image: left panel gone]

Edit: I assume the long input boxes where triggered by long file name of background image. I changed its name and it fixed the input width problem. But still there are two problems:

1. Just when i launch the Tweaks app, the window title bar buttons disappear. I have to change the window's width a little to trigger them to appear.
   [image: title bar buttons are gone]

2.The first problem still remains. the left title bar doesn't show up unless increase the window width. (It was not the case when i installed the os)
[image: left panel doesn't show up]
[image: after i increase the window's width]

Comment: I can definitely reproduce the disappearance of the left panel. That seems to me done deliberately: a left arrow appears in case you want to go back. I can't however reproduce the input fields being stretched to their maximum. I seem to remember that the layout of this panel is handled by some CSS somewhere. Perhaps reinstall `gnome-tweaks`?

Comment: Maybe uninstall and re install?

Comment: @jos Yes i noticed the left arrow but the arrow appeared since the problem started, i always had a left panel, and i think the left arrow was only supposed to appear if the width of the window is very short (which is the stretched inputs are making it think the space is small. I'll try to find the CSS files and change the values to see if it makes any difference

Comment: Revert to a standard theme and see whether the issue persists. If not, then you know the cause of the problem.

Comment: @vanadium That was not it

Comment: It will be good to add that information to the question so everyone knows you verified this. In addition, add your Ubuntu version: it may be version dependent. I cannot reproduce any of these problems on Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: @vanadium oh i forgot about that, thank you